# Copy the required data in text file using R

Tags: r

Question: Input data is the text file. Copy only Statistics data and paste it in another text file.
          We can see in the output only statistics data. But ignore package data in text

Input:

> **Statistics - R is statistical software which is used for data analysis. It includes a huge number of statistical procedures such as
>   t-test, chi-square tests, standard linear models, instrumental
>   variables estimation, local polynomial regressions, etc. It also
>   provides high-level graphics capabilities.**
>
> **R provides a wide variety of statistical and graphical techniques, including linear and nonlinear modeling, classical statistical tests,
>   time-series analysis, classification, clustering, and others.**
>
> **R is easily extensible through functions and extensions, and the R community is noted for its active contributions in terms of
>   packages.**
>
> Packages - The capabilities of R are extended through user-created
>   packages, which allow specialized statistical techniques, graphical
>   devices (ggplot2), import/export capabilities, reporting tools (knitr,
>   Sweave), etc.
>
> These packages are developed primarily in R, and sometimes in Java, C
>   and Fortran. A core set of packages is included with the installation
>   of R, with more than 5,800 additional packages and 120,000 functions
>
> **Statistics - R is an object oriented programming language.**
>
> **S-PLUS is a commercial version of the same S programming language that R is a free version**
>
> **SAS is proprietary software that can be used with very large datasets such as census data.**
>
> Packages - Other R package resources include Crantastic, a community
>   site for rating and reviewing all CRAN packages, and R-Forge.
>
> Version 0.16 – This is the last alpha version developed primarily by
>   Ihaka and Gentleman. Much of the basic functionality from the "White
>   Book" (see S history) was implemented. The mailing lists commenced on
>   April 1, 1997.

**Output:**

> **Statistics - R is statistical software which is used for data analysis. It includes a huge number of statistical procedures such as
>   t-test, chi-square tests, standard linear models, instrumental
>   variables estimation, local polynomial regressions, etc. It also
>   provides high-level graphics capabilities.**
>
> **R provides a wide variety of statistical and graphical techniques, including linear and nonlinear modeling, classical statistical tests,
>   time-series analysis, classification, clustering, and others.**
>
> **R is easily extensible through functions and extensions, and the R community is noted for its active contributions in terms of
>   packages.**
>
> **Statistics - R is an object oriented programming language.**
>
> **S-PLUS is a commercial version of the same S programming language that R is a free version**
>
> **SAS is proprietary software that can be used with very large datasets such as census data.**

R Code:

```
setwd("xxx")

text <- readLines("data.txt")

q3<-data.frame(text)

df<- q3[!(is.na(q3$text) | q3$text==""), ]

q4<-data.frame(df)

a<-Search(q4, "Statistics")

View(a)
```

Only the word containing Statistics Paragraph is captured but not the rest.
Need the help to Build R Code

Comment: R is a poor tool for this job.  I would suggest, sed, grep, perl, python...

Comment: Does a paragraph consist of one line?

Comment: Paragraph contains multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_extract_all:

```
left.border <- "Statistics"
rigth.border <- "Packages"
pattern <- paste0(left.border, "(.*?)", right.border)
str_extract_all(text,pattern)
[[1]]
[1] "Statistics - R is statistical software which is used for data analysis. It includes a huge number of statistical procedures such as t-test, chi-square tests, standard linear models, instrumental variables estimation, local polynomial regressions, etc. It also provides high-level graphics capabilities.\n\nR provides a wide variety of statistical and graphical techniques, including linear and nonlinear modeling, classical statistical tests, time-series analysis, classification, clustering, and others.\n\nR is easily extensible through functions and extensions, and the R community is noted for its active contributions in terms of packages.\n\nPackages"
[2] "Statistics - R is an object oriented programming language.\n\nS-PLUS is a commercial version of the same S programming language that R is a free version\n\nSAS is proprietary software that can be used with very large datasets such as census data.\n\nPackages"
```

Then, you can remplace right.border with empty space to remove "Packages" at the end.

Bests,
ZP